# Invoke a method in the MainWindow from ChildWindow loaded using MEF

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mef

How to invoke a method in the MainWindow from ChildWindow loaded using MEF

*Both Main App and the Mef library share the same interface library*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the MainWindow reference to the ChildWindow in the ChildWindow constructor. Make the necessary methods public in the MainWindow. Then you could call them from ChildWindow.